# Incorporating GUI into my crop and stack program

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, directory

I am new to python (3.8) and I just wrote a program that will take the images in a directory and crop them and then stack them all. I am currently trying to add a GUI to make it look nicer. I have read a few guides on how to use tkinter and they all talk about each widget individually. I am a little confused on the notation for using Entry information from the GUI to put into the program to run. I have wrote a general GUI for the program. In my program, I have it where the file directory for the input files and the save location as constant and the user can input (x1,y1), (x2,y2) and number of images. If I want my GUI to have a prompt for the file directory for input and save, I have been trying to do this:

```
def inputfile():
    master.filename = filedialog.askdirectory()
    print(master.filename)
...
input = Button(master, text="Input Files", command="inputfile")
input.grid(column=5, row=6, columnspan=2, pady=6)
```

and then in my code, replace the directory with filename.get()

```
for filename in natsorted(
        glob.glob("..\\One_Dimensional_Reaction_Diffusion_Program\\image_crop_input\\" + "*.*", 
        recursive=True)):
    img = Image.open(filename)
```

I also tried replacing all my x1,y1,x2,y2 with values of my code with x1input.get(). Is this the correct way of doing this?

Attached are the program and GUI code. Thank you for your time.

Program

```
from PIL import Image
from natsort import natsorted
import glob
import gc

# Convert coordinate list into variables
print("Type in the coordinates for the upper left (x1,y1) and bottom right (x2,y2) points")
coordinates = list(map(int, input("Separate values with a space (x1 y1 x2 y2): ").strip().split()))[:4]
x1, y1, x2, y2 = coordinates
image_count = int(input("How many images are being stacked? "))
print("Generating image...")

# Generate final image first
# Width dependent on whether image is horizontal or vertical
if (y2 - y1) > (x2 - x1):
    width = (y2 - y1)
    height = (x2 - x1)
else:
    width = (x2 - x1)
    height = (y2 - y1)

# Width is constant, total_height accounts for height above and the total number of images
total_height = (image_count * height)
new_im = Image.new('RGB', (width, total_height))  # Create a new colored image (RGB)

# Keep outside of loop, if not, will reset y_offset each time
# Indicates position of where to paste cropped image
# Counter used to show progress of program
y_offset = 0
counter = 0

# Accessing all the files using the glob module
# The function natsorted sorts values the way Windows does
# ..\\ allows the program to obtained images from the data file relative to the script's location
# Opens all the files with the variable img in folder and adds them one by one to a list named image_list
for filename in natsorted(
        glob.glob("..\\One_Dimensional_Reaction_Diffusion_Program\\image_crop_input\\" + "*.*", recursive=True)):
    img = Image.open(filename)

    # Cropping function
    selected_region = (x1, y1, x2, y2)  # selected region from previous user input
    cropped_region = img.crop(selected_region)  # taking opened image and cropping to selected region
    if (y2 - y1) > (x2 - x1):  # If cropped area is vertical, rotate into horizontal position
        rotated_image = cropped_region.rotate(90, expand=1)  # Expand 1 ensures image isn't cut off while rotating
    else:
        rotated_image = cropped_region  # Does nothing if image is horizontal
    img.close()  # Closes the initially opened image
    gc.collect()

    new_im.paste(rotated_image, (0, y_offset))  # (x,y) indicates which direction to offset in
    y_offset += rotated_image.size[1]  # y_offset (which had position 0) + the height of the image
    counter += 1
    print(counter, " out of ", image_count, "completed.")  # Shows progress of program
    if counter == image_count:  # Will stop program when counter reaches number of images
        break
final_im = new_im.rotate(180, expand=1)  # stacking goes from top to bottom, rotate images at the end
final_im.save("..\\One_Dimensional_Reaction_Diffusion_Program\\image_crop_output\\stacked_image.tiff", quality=95)
print("Image completed and can be found in the output folder.")
input("Press ENTER to close program.")  # prevents prompt from instantly closing
```

GUI code

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from PIL import Image
from natsort import natsorted
import glob
import gc

master = Tk()
master.title("One Dimensional Reaction Diffusion Program")
master.geometry("440x270")

def inputfile():
    master.filename = filedialog.askdirectory()
    print(master.filename)


header1 = Label(master, text="One Dimensional Reaction Diffusion Program\n"
                             "Created by: Alexander Tang\n")

header1.grid(sticky="N", columnspan=8)
instructions = Label(master, text="Type in the coordinates for the upper left (x1,y1) and bottom right (x2,y2) points:")
instructions.grid(sticky="W", columnspan=8)

x1 = Label(master, text="x1: ")
x1.grid(sticky="E", column=0, row=2)
x1input = Entry(master, width=5)
x1input.grid(sticky="W", column=1, row=2)

y1 = Label(master, text="y1: ")
y1.grid(sticky="E", column=2, row=2)
y1input = Entry(master, width=5)
y1input.grid(sticky="W", column=3, row=2)

x2 = Label(master, text="x2: ")
x2.grid(sticky="E", column=4, row=2)
x2input = Entry(master, width=5)
x2input.grid(sticky="W", column=5, row=2)

y2 = Label(master, text="y2: ")
y2.grid(sticky="E", column=6, row=2)
y2input = Entry(master, width=5)
y2input.grid(sticky="W", column=7, row=2, pady=12)

count = Label(master, text="How many images are being stacked? ")
count.grid(sticky="W", column=0, row=4, columnspan=4)
countinput = Entry(master, width=5)
countinput.grid(stick="W", column=5, row=4, pady=3)

step1 = Label(master, text="1. Select the file location: ")
step1.grid(sticky="W", column=0, row=6, columnspan=4)
step2 = Label(master, text="2. Select the save location: ")
step2.grid(sticky="W", column=0, row=7, columnspan=4)

input = Button(master, text="Input Files", command="inputfile")
input.grid(column=5, row=6, columnspan=2, pady=6)
output = Button(master, text="Output Location")
output.grid(column=5, row=7, columnspan=2)
run = Button(master, text="Run", font="Helvetica, 18", bg="blue", fg="white")
run.grid(sticky="S", column=5, row=8, columnspan=2, pady=6)



mainloop()
```

Comment: it has to be function's name in `command=inputfile`, not string `"inputfile"`

Comment: original code (which processes image) put in function and then button can run it. If you don't put it in function then `import` will run this code at start - it will not wait for GUI. And don't use `input()` in this code. If you want to run it also without GUI then you can use `if __name__ == '__main__': coordinates = input() ; your_function(coordinates) ; input("Press ENTER")`

Comment: you should even get directory as parameter -  `your_function(coordinates, directory)`

Answer (score 0):

First code which you use to process image you have to put in function (but without `input()`) so you could run it with arguments

```
 def process(directory, coordinates, image_count, outputdirectory=None):
```

and then you may use `input()` or GUI or web page to get arguments and run this function

In the same file I use

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

to run this script and use `input()` to get arguments and run `process()`.

It can be also imported to other script and run `process()` without starting `main()`

**imageprocess.py**

```
from PIL import Image
from natsort import natsorted
import glob
import gc
import os   # os.path.join(directory, filename)

def process(directory, coordinates, image_count, outputdirectory=None):

    x1, y1, x2, y2 = coordinates

    # Generate final image first
    # Width dependent on whether image is horizontal or vertical
    if (y2 - y1) > (x2 - x1):
        width = (y2 - y1)
        height = (x2 - x1)
    else:
        width = (x2 - x1)
        height = (y2 - y1)

    # Width is constant, total_height accounts for height above and the total number of images
    total_height = (image_count * height)
    new_im = Image.new('RGB', (width, total_height))  # Create a new colored image (RGB)

    # Keep outside of loop, if not, will reset y_offset each time
    # Indicates position of where to paste cropped image
    # Counter used to show progress of program
    y_offset = 0
    counter = 0

    # Accessing all the files using the glob module
    # The function natsorted sorts values the way Windows does
    # ..\\ allows the program to obtained images from the data file relative to the script's location
    # Opens all the files with the variable img in folder and adds them one by one to a list named image_list
    for filename in natsorted(glob.glob( os.path.join(directory, "*.*"), recursive=True)):
        img = Image.open(filename)

        # Cropping function
        selected_region = (x1, y1, x2, y2)  # selected region from previous user input
        cropped_region = img.crop(selected_region)  # taking opened image and cropping to selected region
        if (y2 - y1) > (x2 - x1):  # If cropped area is vertical, rotate into horizontal position
            rotated_image = cropped_region.rotate(90, expand=1)  # Expand 1 ensures image isn't cut off while rotating
        else:
            rotated_image = cropped_region  # Does nothing if image is horizontal
        img.close()  # Closes the initially opened image
        gc.collect()

        new_im.paste(rotated_image, (0, y_offset))  # (x,y) indicates which direction to offset in
        y_offset += rotated_image.size[1]  # y_offset (which had position 0) + the height of the image
        counter += 1
        print(counter, " out of ", image_count, "completed.")  # Shows progress of program
        if counter == image_count:  # Will stop program when counter reaches number of images
            break
    final_im = new_im.rotate(180, expand=1)  # stacking goes from top to bottom, rotate images at the end

    if outputdirectory is None:
        outputdirectory = directory
    final_im.save( os.path.join(outputdirectory, "stacked_image.tiff"), quality=95)

def main():
    # Convert coordinate list into variables
    print("Type in the coordinates for the upper left (x1,y1) and bottom right (x2,y2) points")
    coordinates = list(map(int, input("Separate values with a space (x1 y1 x2 y2): ").strip().split()))[:4]
    image_count = int(input("How many images are being stacked? "))
    print("Generating image...")

    process(directory, coordinates, image_count)

    print("Image completed and can be found in the output folder.")
    input("Press ENTER to close program.")  # prevents prompt from instantly closing

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Now you can import it to GUI and use button to run function which get arguments from GUI and run `process()`.

BTW: it has to be function name `command=function_name`, not string `"function_name"`

**gui.py**

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import messagebox
from PIL import Image
from natsort import natsorted
import glob
import gc

import imageprocess

# --- functions ---

def inputfile():
    master.inputdirectory = filedialog.askdirectory()
    print(master.inputdirectory)

def outputfile():
    master.outputdirectory = filedialog.askdirectory()
    print(master.outputdirectory)

def run():
    try:
        coordinates = [int(x1input.get()), int(x2input.get()), int(y1input.get()), int(y2input.get())]
        image_count = int(countinput.get())

        imageprocess.process(master.inputdirectory, coordinates, image_count, master.outputdirectory)

    except Exception as ex:
        print('ex:', ex)
        messagebox.showwarning("Warning", "Wrong arguments:\n" + str(ex))

# --- main ---

master = Tk()

master.inputdirectory = None   # default value at start
master.outputdirectory = None  # default value at start

master.title("One Dimensional Reaction Diffusion Program")
master.geometry("440x270")

header1 = Label(master, text="One Dimensional Reaction Diffusion Program\n"
                             "Created by: Alexander Tang\n")

header1.grid(sticky="N", columnspan=8)
instructions = Label(master, text="Type in the coordinates for the upper left (x1,y1) and bottom right (x2,y2) points:")
instructions.grid(sticky="W", columnspan=8)

x1 = Label(master, text="x1: ")
x1.grid(sticky="E", column=0, row=2)
x1input = Entry(master, width=5)
x1input.grid(sticky="W", column=1, row=2)

y1 = Label(master, text="y1: ")
y1.grid(sticky="E", column=2, row=2)
y1input = Entry(master, width=5)
y1input.grid(sticky="W", column=3, row=2)

x2 = Label(master, text="x2: ")
x2.grid(sticky="E", column=4, row=2)
x2input = Entry(master, width=5)
x2input.grid(sticky="W", column=5, row=2)

y2 = Label(master, text="y2: ")
y2.grid(sticky="E", column=6, row=2)
y2input = Entry(master, width=5)
y2input.grid(sticky="W", column=7, row=2, pady=12)

count = Label(master, text="How many images are being stacked? ")
count.grid(sticky="W", column=0, row=4, columnspan=4)
countinput = Entry(master, width=5)
countinput.grid(stick="W", column=5, row=4, pady=3)

step1 = Label(master, text="1. Select the file location: ")
step1.grid(sticky="W", column=0, row=6, columnspan=4)
step2 = Label(master, text="2. Select the save location: ")
step2.grid(sticky="W", column=0, row=7, columnspan=4)

btn_input = Button(master, text="Input Files", command=inputfile)
btn_input.grid(column=5, row=6, columnspan=2, pady=6)

btn_output = Button(master, text="Output Location", command=outputfile)
btn_output.grid(column=5, row=7, columnspan=2)

btn_run = Button(master, text="Run", font="Helvetica, 18", bg="blue", fg="white", command=run)
btn_run.grid(sticky="S", column=5, row=8, columnspan=2, pady=6)

mainloop()
```

It need to check values in widgets and display window with warning when arguments are wrong. But code starts working